# Path of War Defense conundrum?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, path-of-war

Path of War has Strike, Boost, Counter, and Stance.

Strike - usually an attack and extra damage and some effects

Boost - extra damage usually

Counter - repost, dodge, reaction

Stance - at will mods to certain aspects of combat

So my friend and I got in to a bit of a debate. Some Strikes and Boost can catch a target Flat-Footed. But if said target has a Counter,...can they counter the Strike/Boost while Flat-Footed? Specially if they don't have Uncanny Dodge?

Answer (score 4):

### General case:

The flat-footed defender cannot counter. Counters (like [Flat Iron Riposte](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/broken-blade-maneuvers/#TOC-Flat-Iron-Riposte)) need a immediate action to be initiated and "[you also cannot use an immediate action if you are flat-footed](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Immediate-Actions)". So if the attacker use a strike like [Hunting Serpent Blow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/steel-serpent-maneuvers/#TOC-Hunting-Serpent-Blow) which render the target flat-footed, the defender cannot initiate a counter against this attack.

If the attacker use a boost like like [Taunting Laugh](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/black-seraph-maneuvers/taunting-laugh), the target is rendered flat-footed before the eventual strike or regular attack, and won't be able to counter.

Note that:

- in some strikes like [Pommel Bash](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/broken-blade-maneuvers/#TOC-Pommel-Bash), "the initiator makes an attack against the target’s flat-footed armor class", in which case the defender is not caught flat-footed and can initiate a counter.
- some strikes like [Crushing Blow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/primal-fury-maneuvers/#TOC-Crushing-Blow) render the defender flat-footed after the attack, so they can initiate a counter before.
- some strikes like [Offensive Roll](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/thrashing-dragon-maneuvers/#TOC-Offensive-Roll) have wordings that could be interpreted as "the attacker treats the defender as flat-footed (e.g. for sneak attacks, and Dex bonus to AC), but the defender isn't really flat-footed and can act (e.g. with a counter)". Also strikes that could or should be similar (like [Phantom Wind Ray](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/solar-wind-maneuvers/#TOC-Phantom-Wind-Ray) and [Hunting Serpent Blow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/steel-serpent-maneuvers/#TOC-Hunting-Serpent-Blow), or [Offensive Roll](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/thrashing-dragon-maneuvers/#TOC-Offensive-Roll) and [Devastation Roll](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/thrashing-dragon-maneuvers/#TOC-Devastation-Roll)) don't have the same wordings.
- some counters like [Clock Watcher](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/riven-hourglass-maneuvers/) can be initiated even when flat-footed (although this one isn't really useful against an incoming attack).

### [Uncanny Dodge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue#TOC-Uncanny-Dodge-Ex-):

You can't be caught flat-footed, so you can initiate a counter (if you still have your immediate action).

Comment: Offensive Roll says, "If successful, the target is considered flat-footed and the strike inflicts an additional 1d6 points of damage. " I'm pretty sure that should mean *the target is considered flat-footed against this attack* rather than *the target is considered flat-footed forevermore*, but I totally respect that literal reading.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I'm not 100% sure, but I would say that even with your interpretation, as the target is flat-footed against this attack, they can't initiate a counter.

Comment: I'd disagree. There's a difference between an attacker treating the defender as if the defender were flat-footed and the defender actually being flat-footed. (But what do I know? Maybe we could get @KRyan over here to confirm; he, like, works with these dudes sometimes.)

Comment: Good point. I'll try to find if there are strikes/boosts which flat-foot with less ambiguity, and if not, make a correction.